# Dependently typed language best suited to “real world” programming?

Tags: programming-languages

Which *dependently typed* programming languages could be used for real world *application development*? I will mostly be writing toy applications at first, after that maybe web development or a simple DBMS.

These are some points, that I think are important:

- documentation
- example programs
- a good/big standard library
- an easy to use foreign function interface
- a community of people using the language for real world tasks
- tool support

I am aware that there is currently no language that meets all these requirements. I'd like to know which one comes closest.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you are asking for something that just doesn't exist yet. Things such as big libraries, etc general only come with maturity + large community bases, of which they have no reached.

You can find a list of them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which will at least let you filter out those that are not actively developed.

What are you reasons for wanting to use a dependently-typed language for web development, etc?

Comment: I've been playing around with ATS a bit. I'm mostly just curious whether it can be done and whether it would actually have advantages over languages without dependent types. Is there a language with a cgi interface or any other kind of integration with a web server? I know the wikipedia list...

Comment: If you can make it an executable you can surely make it work with CGI. Have I seen any? No. Can I find any? No. I'm not sure what advantages it would have over the current prevailing languages though...

Answer (score 2):

Probably [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) is the most alive of these, but it's hardly 'commercial grade' software yet, it's more 'bleeding edge'.